# Использование декоратора @property и @setter в python

Tags: python, ооп, декоратор

```
class N:
    def __init__(self):
       self.a = False
       self.b = True
```

Пытаюсь понять как использовать декоратор при boolean значении, чтобы при изменении значения переменной а - изменялась переменная b.

```
@property
def c(self):
    return self.a

@с.setter
def c(self):
    if self.a not self.b:
        self.a == True
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@c.setter
def c(self, b):      # Метод принимает ещё один аргумент кроме self
    self.b = b       # Его нужно сохранить в self.b
                     # А дальше уже можно делать как было у вас
    if not self.b:
        self.a = True
```

И, кстати, несколько замечаний:

- слово `class` нужно писать ТОЛЬКО с маленькой буквы.
- в `__init__` вы забыли двоеточие
- вы `@с.setter` написали с русской `c` в начале
- вместо того, чтобы хранить две булевых переменных с противоположным значением, проще хранить только одну, а вторую высчитывать из первой в тот момент, когда к ней обращаются.

Comment: А чему будет равен этот аргумент? True или false, соответственно?

Comment: Что туда передаст тот, кто вызовет этот сеттер, то там и окажется.

Comment: @Xander, поправь, пожалуйста, последнюю строку self.a = True

Comment: @JackWolf, спасибо, у автора в исходном коде столько косяков, что в одиночку все не найти ))

Comment: без проблем) а можете, пожалуйста, сказать, когда подобные "махинации" с proterty и что-то_там.setter, нужно использовать?

Comment: самый очевидный пример, когда тебе потребуется readonly аттрибут. переменную содержащую свойство ты инкапсулируешь и предоставляешь только getter для чтения этого свойства пользователям класса.

Comment: @JackWolf, общий ответ - в тех случаях, когда вы хотите, чтобы при каждом обращении к атрибуту выполнялась некоторая дополнительная логика. Ну или когда значение атрибута не хранится в явном виде, а должно вычисляться при обращении к нему.